# BASH Run multiple scripts from a another script

Tags: bash

I have a doubt about running multiple scripts from a third one:

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script 1"
#... and also download a csv file from gdrive
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script 2"
```

third.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

BEGIN {
    print "script3"
}
```

I would like a 4th script that run them in order, I've tried the following but only runs the first script.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( first.sh second.sh )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   chmod +x $i
   echo $i
   . $i 
done
```

But only runs the first script and nothing else.

Thank you very much for the support!
Santiago

Comment: Loop through the index or the array, something like: `for i in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "${array[i]}}"; done`

Comment: Do you want to *run* the scripts, or to *source* them?

Comment: You're probably looking for`./"$i"` instead of `. "$i"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't source an awk script into a shell script. Run the script instead of sourcing it.

`.` (aka `source`) executes commands from the file in the current shell, it disregards the shebang line.

What you need instead is `./`, i.e. path to the script, unless `.` is part of your $PATH (which is usually not recommended ).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

array=( first.sh second.sh )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   chmod +x "$i"
   echo "$i"
   ./"$i"  # <---
done
```

Why is the second script not running? I guess the first script contains an `exit`, which when sourced exits the shell, i.e. it doesn't continue running the outer wrapper.

Comment: This `"$i"` is not working at all. The dot is needed but with a `"/"`, like that `./"$i"`, see?)

Comment: @Ivan: It depends on the setting of $PATH, but generally, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: But `./` is a path, while `.` with a space is a builtin command.